# Debugging Servers

Tags: c++, debugging, remote-debugging

I have a C++ server. In developing and testing the code the client side can be run under the control of debug in the DE, but I have assumed that debugging the server means I have to  resort to embedding print statements to produce diagnostics to the "terminal" and to log files, which is what I do.

Do "debug wrappers" exist such that you invoke the server under the control of an enclosing debug environment. Such a wrapper would need its own gui and access to the source code.. and yes I'm out of my depth now.

Can anyone help, or explain to me gently why its a dumb question?

Comment: Remote debugging is common in several environments. What OS are you talking about?

Comment: The server is IDL which uses an Eclipse DE. I'm using Eclipse for the DE for C++ on Redhat Linux.

Comment: Correction Doh! The client is written in IDL which uses an Eclipse DE. THe Server is is wriiten in c++ using Eclipse DE in Redhat Linux.

Comment: Thank you Roger - the phrase "Remote Debugging" has led me to find GDB, and I will investigate that. Any further help most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that a server is just a program, and a debugger is just a program. The only magic is that the run-time environment (the operating system) makes it possible for the debugger program to examine and manipulate the other program. The debugger needs to be told which program it is to debug. *How* you do that depends on the debugger. It helps if you understand a little more about your computer and its operating system than just some GUI magic.

For example, on Unix I might start a server using the following shell-script command:

```
 myserver &
```

I might start it in the foreground thus:

```
 myserver
```

I would start it under the control of the `gdb` debugger, in the foreground, thus:

```
 gdb myserver
```

Comment: The IDL client spawns the C++ server and opens a two-way pipe. So my client can Spawn

Comment: The IDL client spawns the C++ server and opens a two-way pipe. It then uses stdin and stdout for communication between client and server. I'm guessing that GDB is also using them and therefore that proabably skuppers me using that.